# Images are not sizing right for an image button

Tags: android, image, imagebutton

I'm trying to set an image for and image button in android studio, but when I add the image asset it forces the size down to icon sizes instead of the size i made the image (300x450px) the image file is a jpeg. any clue how to make it size the image properly? Forgive me if its something obvious that I'm overlooking this is the first app I've written .

Comment: What is forcing it to be smaller? Is it just rendering smaller, is the IDE making it smaller? We need a little more info to help.

Comment: How do you know its not 300x450px? Depending on the DPI of the display on the phone you are testing with this could be pretty small.

Comment: @BlargleMonster I have no clue. It could be, like startoftext said, that I didn't account for the DPI of the phone I'm testing with, a Galaxy s5, and if I could figure out the ppi broken down by x and y axis I would try scaling the image up to try that

Comment: so after scaling the image up to 810x1215px (which should be roughly 300x450dp if the formula i found was right) I can safely say it is probably the IDE shrinking the size of the image

Answer (score 0):

**1.** to add image, you can just copy it to *drawable-hdpi* or other similar folder

**2.** Here is how I use ImageButton

You should use or *android:src* or *android:background*

**android:src** - shows image with original scale

**android:background** - image adjusted to button scale

```
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/play"
            android:background="@drawable/play"/>
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: scaling the button I can do just fine, it's scaling the image to match the scale of the button that im having problems with

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out how to fix the problem I was having. I scaled the image up from 300x450px to 810x1215px and converted the 810x1215px file to a 9patch png, because letting Android studio convert it to png from jpg was causing the loss of data in the image resulting in the image being smaller than it should have been.